# Spring Boot Conditional Resource Importing

Tags: spring, spring-boot, resources

We can import an XML resource in Spring Boot project like this:

```
@ImportResource("${locationProperty:defaultLocation}")
```

But I need to import this file according to a condition. Such as, if a property value is false, it shouldn't import this file, it it's true, it should import.

How can I conditionally import a resource in Spring Boot application?

Comment: was my answer useful?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ConditionalOnProperty](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnProperty.html)

Something like:

```java
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "beans", name = "additional")
@ImportResource("${path-to-bean-config}")
public class AdditionalXmlBeans{
}
```